# Pointer events not firing in react-three-fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to add pointer events to a GLTF file loaded in react-three-fiber using GLTFJSX. However, the pointer events don't fire, and I can't figure out why.

I have tried adding the same events into other similar code sandboxes, and it works — so why wouldn't it work in this example, if I'm doing basically the same thing?

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-brook-h8rhs?file=/src/App.js

- Expected behavior: When you hover over the model or click on it, it should be logged to the console.
- Actual behavior: Only the `onPointerMissed` event ever fires.

Sometimes, the `onPointerOver` and `onPointerOut` events do work. This seems to work at random — sometimes it works, but most of the time it just doesn't.

Am I missing something obvious?

#### Edit

When changed to `mesh`, the pointer events work. So the issue is related directly to `skinnedMesh` not detecting pointer events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `SkinnedMesh` modifies the vertex positions in the graphics card (GPU), so the JavaScript side doesn't know that the vertices have been moved when performing the hit-test (also known as Raycasting). Take a look at the screenshots below:

#### Mesh:

When you use `Mesh`, the vertices show up where `geometry.attributes.position` indicates. The shape is small and far away, but your mouse-events work as expected.
[image]

#### SkinnedMesh:

When you use `SkinnedMesh`, the vertices are translated in the GPU to be much closer, but the raycasting calculation still uses the original `geometry.attributes.position` coordinates to perform the hit-test. That's why you only get the expected mouse events in a very small area inside the red box.
[image]

#### Solutions:

The solution varies based on your use-case but you could do any of the following:

1. Use `Mesh`, and update the `mesh.position` property to move it closer to the camera.
2. If you need `SkinnedMesh`, try to keep the skeleton displacements small enough so their skinned positions don't deviate far from their original positions.
3. You could create an invisible "hitbox" and just add the mouse events to that. This is what most game developers use because it's faster to calculate hit-tests against a very simple geometry:

```jsx
var hitGeom = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var hitMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({visible: false});
// ...
<mesh geometry={hitGeom} material={hitMat}>
```

Comment: Very interesting, it didn't even cross my mind. Thanks for the reply and thorough explanation.

In this case, I do need skinnedMesh. I tried using a hitbox before but as this needs to be animated I thought it would be even more difficult to animate both the model and the hitbox.
So I will try to fix this from Blender, by keeping the mesh and skinnedMesh aligned.